# How to transparent Unity3D custom shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader

I have a custom shader which can render texture inside an object (such as : Sphere). But **I can't make it transparent because Unity says there is no `_Color` property added in that shader.**

I am not an expert in Unity Shader, so need some help how to make my existing shader. Here is my shader code.

```
Shader "InsideVisible" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        Cull front
        LOD 100

        Pass 
        {  
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;

                o.vertex     = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                v.texcoord.x = 1 - v.texcoord.x;                
                o.texcoord   = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The shader as posted appears to work correctly when applied in Unity. Are you perhaps trying to access the `_Color` property from a script or something?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to make it transparent through script. The normal standard shader are becoming transparent easily but this custom shader not. Otherwise this shader is working perfectly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your script is probably trying to access a property named `_Color` to set its alpha value, but there is no `_Color` property on this shader, so the script fails.

Also the shader is not set up to render transparency, so we'll need to fix that.

Shader properties are kind of like the public properties you expose on C# classes: the outside world can manipulate them to change the way the shader renders.

In the fragment, we multiply the image color by the `_Color` property so that it can control tint and alpha.

To make your shader render transparency, you also need to add a few lines to the SubShader and the pragma.

```
Shader "InsideVisible" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Color (RGBA)", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1) // add _Color property
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Cull front 
        LOD 100

        Pass 
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert alpha
            #pragma fragment frag alpha

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t 
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f 
            {
                float4 vertex  : SV_POSITION;
                half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _Color;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;

                o.vertex     = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                v.texcoord.x = 1 - v.texcoord.x;
                o.texcoord   = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord) * _Color; // multiply by _Color
                return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's working now. Thanks a lot! That's the right thing I was searching for 10 days long!

Comment: Thanks. I found I didn't need 'Cull front' in my case as this removed the actual shading.